# Ruby Koan: test_nil_is_an_object

Tags: ruby

I have recently tried sharpening my rails skills with this tool:

http://github.com/edgecase/ruby_koans

but I am having trouble passing some tests. Also I am not sure if I'm doing some things correctly since the objective is just to pass the test, there are a lot of ways in passing it and I may be doing something that isn't up to standards.

Is there a way to confirm if I'm doing things right?

a specific example:

in about_nil,

```
 def test_nil_is_an_object
   assert_equal __, nil.is_a?(Object), "Unlike NULL in other languages"
 end
```

so is it telling me to check if that second clause is equal to an object(so i can say nil is an object) or just put `assert_equal true, nil.is_a?(Object)` because the statement is true?

and the next test:

```
def test_you_dont_get_null_pointer_errors_when_calling_methods_on_nil
  # What happens when you call a method that doesn't exist.  The
  # following begin/rescue/end code block captures the exception and
  # make some assertions about it.
  begin
    nil.some_method_nil_doesnt_know_about
  rescue Exception => ex
    # What exception has been caught?
    assert_equal __, ex.class

    # What message was attached to the exception?
    # (HINT: replace __ with part of the error message.)
    assert_match(/__/, ex.message)
  end
end
```

Im guessing I should put a "No method error" string in the assert_match, but what about the assert_equal?

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about the koans, gotta try them. Perhaps asking for help, or looking for advice on things that you don't think are right, but being more specific, will get you better answers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`assert_equal true, nil.is_a?(Object)` is indeed the correct solution. The question is "Are nils in Ruby objects or not?", and in Ruby's case, they are. Thus, in order to pass the assertion, you should assert the truth of that test.

In the second example, when you call an undefined method on nil, you get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'foo' for nil:NilClass`. Thus, the exception class is `NoMethodError`, and the message is `undefined method 'foo' for nil:NilClass`. Test the failing behavior in a console, and see what you get from it, and then apply that knowledge to the test.

Comment: thanks for the heads up! so does that mean that i will have to trust my instincts to know if what I did was right? Is there no way to check if what I did was correct and true to the ruby convention?

Comment: sometimes there is more than one correct way to phrase an answer, like real life

Answer (score 5):

Are you running

```
ruby path_to_enlightenment.rb
```

at the command prompt after you correct each test? It will give you lots of help.

Also "remember that silence is sometimes the best answer" -- if you are stumped don't put in anything and the tool will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in holding with the typical TDD motto of Red-Green-Refactor, you should run the test (probably with rake in a separate console) and see the failure happen. From there, they have provided you a few pieces of information about what was expected.

As for style, the koans aren't really teaching that. You should just find and read some code written in ruby to get a feel for the typical conventions and idioms of the ruby community.

Comment: What file would you use `rake` on?

Answer (score 2):

Simplicity is the key with Ruby Koans - when I started it I thought it *must* be harder than what it is, but it's not! Just ask IRB the question Koans is asking you, and after a few you get a feel for it. I've written a blog piece about it to help others, too:

[Ruby Koans Answers](http://astonj.com/tech/ruby-koans-answers/)

Answer (score 1):

I remember when I did this that I tried to out think the test and tried to put in

```
<Answer> and <"Answer">
```

The thing to remember is that the actual class doesn't have to be in a string or something.
So the answer is NOT

```
ex.class, ex.class
```

As suggested above, put the code into irb and execute it.

```
(1..5).class == Range
```

is a big hint